# Should mods be deleting answers that address the question?

Tags: discussion, moderation

As expected in a stack exchange site, there are always those "this is off topic" purists that discourage new users.

Even worse when the mods are going as far as deleting answers.

In my case I asked the same question here and on Quora. Quora had some great answers, so I posted it here. But the mod [shog9](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/8/shog9) took it upon himself to delete my helpful answer.

[image: deleted answer]

The mod could have left a comment which would have prompted me to make improvements. But this seems really ridiculous to get so uptight from the beginning. It is not going to help engagement and gain a diverse set of questions and answers.

Comment: Could the person that downvoted actually make a comment as to why you downvoted the question.

Comment: I won't speak for others, but I downvoted this because you say that the mod could have left a comment, but I clearly see it in your own printscreen, and to me, it is perfectly agreeable too. Your answer is a clear case of plagiarism, it doesn't matter if you asked the same question on Quora, the answer is not yours and you have no copyright over it. Neither does Stack Exchange. If Quora's TOS permits copying content with attribution, then that's the minimum requirement that you could fulfil here (add a link, format the text in blockquote, etc.), but you didn't. Why are you complaining?

Comment: @TildalWave it is absolutely NOT plagarism because I asked the question on Quora and they answered ME without marking as "not for reproduction." On Quora the intent is to share knowledge, mostly by curating.

Comment: Right. Here: [Quora TOS - Quora's Licenses to You](https://www.quora.com/about/tos): _"... (b) attribute Quora by name in readable text and with a human and machine-followable link (an HTML <a> anchor tag) linking back to the page displaying the original source of the content on quora.com on every page that contains Quora content; "_ What doesn't this clear?

Comment: @TildalWave Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JGallardo Out of curiosity, *which question* was this an answer to? I personally don't like this answer because to me it reads like an advertisement (complete with "Click here to buy!" links), but parts of it may be an appropriate response to a question about the differences between training in the US verses <somewhere else>...

Comment: ironic that a question about being off-topic is closed as being off-topic.

Answer (score 18):

Shog9 gave you a detailed reason for deleting this in his comment:

> Please don't post answers that consist entirely of content found elsewhere; that sets a really bad example. Also, text-as-images is really search-unfriendly.

I actually saw your answer and flagged it, saying "Idk what to make of this", for exactly the reasons Shog pointed out; a printscreen of a Quora question for an answer is not good.

Instead, summarise what everyone has answered there, in your own words, and post that.

---

To answer your actual question of "Should mods be deleting answers that address the question?" — no! But that wasn't why your answer was deleted.

Comment: Could have suggested edits though.

Comment: Your post consisted of just an image, with a big wall of text. It needs rewriting completely. I encourage you to write a new answer.